# Any way to derive the Opera extension store url from the extension ID?

Tags: opera-extension

Trying to make my Chrome extension compatible with Opera.

For Chrome I can append the extension ID to "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/" and I can get the Chrome Web Store url of that extension.

Does Opera have anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just use:

```
https://addons.opera.com/extensions/details/app_id/[extension_id]
```

For example, for AdBlock:

```
https://addons.opera.com/extensions/details/app_id/aobdicepooefnbaeokijohmhjlleamfj
```